# Advanced authorization strategies in .net

Tags: .net, authorization

I'm looking for existing solution for advanced authorization (not authentication) in .net. Requirements are bellow:

1. Define custom application operation on application entities. Say operation "Update" for      "Meeting" entity.
2. Grant user "User1" to perform operation "Update" only on entity "Meeting" with ID = 1.
3. When operation "Update" is performed check if current user ("User1") has access granted to "Meeting" entity with ID = 1.

So I need some existing solution to authorize specific objects for operation. As I know some solutions (AzMan) provide authorization abilities, but only for operations as units (not for concrete objects).

Comment: Do you mean you want to authorize instances of specific classes authorization based on a specific user?

Comment: I mean specific entities. "Meeting" entity describes real event. I have a record about the event in database and class that represent it in program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with things like the `PrincipalPermissionsAttribute`.  If you're dealing with Windows authorization and things like AzMan, you can simply create users assign them roles and log them into your application (or use the currently logged in user information).  If you want to use custom authentication you have to deal with roles yourself and set the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with something like `GenericPincipal`.  You can then use `PrincipalPermissionsAttribute` on methods to ensure only principals with specific roles and execute the method.  For example:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"UserUpdater")]
public void UpdateUserName(string name)
{
//...
}
```

If you want to do the authorization yourself, once you've authorized a user you can set the principal with something like:

```
var identity = new GenericIdentity("Bill");
var roles = new[] { @"UserUpdater" };
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

You'll have to deal with `SecurityException` when users without that role invoke the method.  The assumption is that something else checks the role and simply doesn't execute that method...

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I looking a bit different solution. I want to authorize specific instance of class that represents real unique entity (like meeting) rather than static class.

Comment: There's nothing to do that inherently.  The object itself would have to perform the check against `CurrentPrincipal`s roles.  This could be done with the Decorator Pattern along with the Strategy Pattern to keep it separate from the entity.  Alternatively you could use AOP to intercept calls into entity and replace them with security checks before passing it along to the object; but AOP is generally tricky in .NET.